# Ubuntu 18.04 google chrome crashes when gnome shell extensions are loaded

Tags: drivers, graphics, google-chrome, opengl

I wanted to use the current version of chrome.  But it seems that unless I disable all my gnome shell extensions first it's not going to happen.

I also tried based on previous questions disabling the sandbox and gpu with no effect.  Ouput here:

Also tried deleting the google-chrome directory in ~/.config/

```
[I]  ~/downloads  google-chrome --no-sandbox --disable-gpu
[I]  ~/downloads  google-chrome
[25111:25111:0925/181842.865622:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[25111:25111:0925/181843.063204:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[I]  ~/downloads  google-chrome
[26005:26005:0925/182004.342502:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[26005:26005:0925/182004.532653:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
^C⏎                                                                                                                                                           [I]  ~/downloads  google-chrome
[27395:27395:0925/182113.790411:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[27395:27395:0925/182113.950042:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[27304:27463:0925/182216.357162:FATAL:bus.cc(1215)] D-Bus connection was disconnected. Aborting.
fish: “google-chrome” terminated by signal SIGTRAP (Trace or breakpoint trap)
[I]  ✘  ~/downloads  google-chrome
[4750:4750:0925/182437.014522:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[4750:4750:0925/182437.167120:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command

^C⏎                                                                                                                                                           [I]  ~/downloads  google-chrome
[7102:7102:0925/182637.328197:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[7102:7102:0925/182637.526328:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[7102:7102:0925/182714.072002:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[I]  ~/downloads  [7977:7977:0925/182751.089945:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[7977:7977:0925/182751.423313:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[7977:7977:0925/182810.783713:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[7977:7977:0925/182818.426713:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```